# what's the difference between ending with a trailing slash and without it in file path when using ls command

Tags: ls

what's the difference between the following commands?

```
ls -al

ls -al /
```

because it shows me different content list for them.

I tried to find the answer but failed, if this is a duplicate question please paste the answer for it.

Comment: `ls -Al` lists file in the current directory and `ls -al` lists file in `/`. What exactly do you have a problem with?

Comment: Hi Arkadiusz and John, your answers are very helpful, my question is about the difference between those two commands, :)

Answer (score 2):

From the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html):

> **ls** [OPTION]... [FILE]...
>
> List  information  about the FILEs (the current directory by default).

So `ls -al` lists the current directory (the default), `ls -al /` lists the root directory. Unless your current directory is the root directory, you’ll get different results.

Answer (score 1):

`ls -al` lists all files and directories in the current directory, because when no directory is specified, `ls` assumes you want it to list the current working directory. You can view the current working directory via the `pwd` command. In most cases the default working directory is your home directory (/home/username) .

`ls -al /` on the other hand lists all files in the root directory (/) instead of the working directory (by default /home/username).
You can change the default working directory via `cd /path/to/desireddirectory`

If you want you default working directory to be `/` then do `cd /`

Comment: ok, thank you. current directory is ok, so i won't change it.